# how to use if else in android

Tags: android, string, if-statement

I am trying to initialize an String array using if else method .. but its not working . How to do it ?

```
if(itemno==2){
        String[] values = new String[] { "Category31", 
                "Category32",
                "Category33",
                "Category34", 
                "Category35", 
                "Category36", 
                "Category37", 
                "Android Example List View" ,
                "daniel",
                "dude",
                "hello",
                "super,","dukker"

               };}

else if(itemno==3){
        String[] values = new String[] { "Category31", 
                "Category32",
                "Category33",
                "Category34", 
                "Category35", 
                "Category36", 
                "Category37", 
                "Android Example List View" ,
                "daniel",
                "dude",
                "hello",
                "super,","dukker"

               };}


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but in adapter is showing error that Variable is not accepted.. help me

Comment: you should look into "java scopes variable" and learn something about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the `values` variable inside the `if`'s block. The scope of the variable in your case is from the `if`'s start, until its end.

```
if(something)
{
   //start of if scope

   String[] values = {"one"};

   //values available here with contents: {"one"}
   //end of if scope
}
else
{
   //start of else scope

   String[] values;

   //values available here - different from the values above. this variable value is null here
   //end of else scope
}
//none of the values declared above are available here. From the compiler's PoW, no values variable has been declared here.
```

A solution to what you are trying to achieve is to move the `values` declaration outside the `if` or `else` scope: put `String[] values;` before the `if`, and remove the `String[]` declarations in the `if` and `else` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your values Variable is inside if bracket it is not accessible
outside please declare it as class Variable and then initialize it in if block.

Answer (score 0):

You are declared values as `local`. So it is accessed only to local, which means inside the `If` block. It can't be accessed outside `If` statement. So please make `String[] values;` at global variable

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is correct regarding if else. To remove the error, declare "String[] values;" outside the if else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare String[] values outside the scope of if else block.